# Node.JS express-validator: get value

Tags: node.js, validation

I'm using express-validator for Node.Js http request validation.

The validation works great, but let say i'm validation a field name "access_token" and i'm using assert method in order to check it in the body,query and url.
How can I get the value that was validated for further use?

```
if (isAccessTokenRequired) {
    req.assert('access_token', '').notEmpty();
    errors = req.validationErrors();
    if (errors || !validateAccessToken(HERE_THE_INPUTED_ACCESS_TOKEN)) {
        app.error(error.api.invalidAccessToken(), res);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Slightly confused, are you just looking to get the `access_token` value ?

Comment: yes, but it could be in the body (in posts) or the query (in get).. I used asserts in order to make sure it exists somewhere, and it does, but how to express-validator return its value to me for further use

Comment: I see, I'm not 100% sure as I've not done it myself, but there is mention about a `formParam` in the validator.. https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator#middleware-options

Comment: is `access_token` sending in request body?

Comment: @nmrony or in the query

Comment: @AsafNevo can't we use express way to get params data like `req.body.access_token` or `req.params.access_token`?

Comment: I don't think express-validator is capable of doing that. I'm afraid you'll have to do it yourself.

Comment: @nmrony of course we can. I just thought that it make sense that the validator is already using the value for validation, he will return it to me for further use

Comment: @AsafNevo I think @razakj is right. After giving a quick look into `node-validator` I see no retrieving function there and not necessarily need to have one for a validation only library :-)